# Create an Identity matrix

Tags: javascript, matrix

I have to create an Identity matrix the following way,

"your Matrix object should have a ‘createIdentity’ function that takes no
parameters. The function should return a newly constructed Matrix object that has its cells set to an
identity matrix. This function should act like a static method in C#. To do this in your JavaScript
object, don’t add the function to the Matrix prototype, but rather to the Matrix object directly. (e.g.
Matrix.createIdentity = function() { etc.)"

What I have done so far is:

```
var Matrix = (function () {
function Matrix(pX0, pX1, pX2, pY0, pY1, pY2, pZ0, pZ1, pZ2) {

    this.matrix = [
        [pX0, pX1, pX2],
        [pY0, pY1, pY2],
        [pZ0, pZ1, pZ2]
    ];
}
Matrix.prototype.getX0 = function () {
    return this.mX0;
};
Matrix.prototype.setX0 = function (pX0) {
    this.mX0 = pX0;
};
Matrix.prototype.getX1 = function () {
    return this.mX1;
};
Matrix.prototype.setX1 = function (pX1) {
    this.mX1 = pX1;
};
Matrix.prototype.getX2 = function () {
    return this.mX2;
};
Matrix.prototype.setX2 = function (pX2) {
    this.mX2 = pX2;
};


Matrix.prototype.getY0 = function () {
    return this.mY0;
};
Matrix.prototype.setY0 = function (pY0) {
    this.mY0 = pY0;
};
Matrix.prototype.getY1 = function () {
    return this.mY1;
};
Matrix.prototype.setY1 = function (pY1) {
    this.mY1 = pY1;
};
Matrix.prototype.getY2 = function () {
    return this.mY2;
};
Matrix.prototype.setY2 = function (pY2) {
    this.mY2 = pY2;
};


Matrix.prototype.getZ0 = function () {
    return this.mZ0;
};
Matrix.prototype.setZ0 = function (pZ0) {
    this.mZ0 = pZ0;
};
Matrix.prototype.getZ1 = function () {
    return this.mZ0;
};
Matrix.prototype.setZ1 = function (pZ1) {
    this.mZ1 = pZ1;
};
Matrix.prototype.getZ2 = function () {
    return this.mZ2;
};
Matrix.prototype.setZ2 = function (pZ2) {
    this.mZ2 = pZ2;
};
Matrix.prototype.getElement = function (pRow, pColumn) {
    return this.matrix[pRow][pColumn];
};

 Matrix.createIdentity = function () {

    var Test = new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    Test = [
        [1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1]
    ];
    return new Test();

};
//Matrix.createIdentity = function () {

//    this.Matrix = [
//        [this.Matrix.setX0(1), this.Matrix.setX1(0), this.Matrix.setX2(0)],
//        [this.Matrix.setY0(0), this.Matrix.setY1(1), this.Matrix.setY2(0)],
//        [this.Matrix.setZ0(0), this.Matrix.setZ1(0), this.Matrix.setZ2(1)]
//    ];
//    return new Matrix();

//};
```

This is the test it has to pass, this test is in jasmine:

```
describe("Create Identity", function () {
    var matrix = Matrix.createIdentity();
    it("Element (0,0) Set", function () {
        expect(matrix.getElement(0, 0)).toEqual(1);
    });

    it("Element (0,1) Set", function () {
        expect(matrix.getElement(0, 1)).toEqual(0);
    });

    it("Element (0,2) Set", function () {
        expect(matrix.getElement(0, 2)).toEqual(0);
    });

    it("Element (1,0) Set", function () {
        expect(matrix.getElement(1, 0)).toEqual(0);
    });

    it("Element (1,1) Set", function () {
        expect(matrix.getElement(1, 1)).toEqual(1);
    });

    it("Element (1,2) Set", function () {
        expect(matrix.getElement(1, 2)).toEqual(0);
    });

    it("Element (2,0) Set", function () {
        expect(matrix.getElement(2, 0)).toEqual(0);
    });

    it("Element (2,1) Set", function () {
        expect(matrix.getElement(2, 1)).toEqual(0);
    });

    it("Element (2,2) Set", function () {
        expect(matrix.getElement(2, 2)).toEqual(1);
    });

});
```

I am failing to see how I am not meeting the requirements of the description given. I have tried a couple of way to pass the test but I cant seem to get it to pass. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function should simply be:

```
Matrix.createIdentity = function () {
    return new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

The existing function returns an object, an Array, that is not a `Matrix` and does not have the `getElement` method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new Matrix object to return. Right now, you are creating a Matrix object, overriding the Matrix object with an array, and then trying to create a new object from the array.

Your code should simply be:

```
Matrix.createIdentity = function () {
    return new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1);
};
```

Comment: Also, your current get and set functions do not work as you no longer have references to mX* and mY* values after you have created the matrix with the given values in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to have no parameters you can simply return a fixed identity matrix:

```
this.matrix = [
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1]
];
```